# ASP.net IE6 issue with quotes

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-6

I am binding the btn.OnClientClick event from server side where i set it to redirect to a page. What IE6 does is, it converts the `'` with`&#39&;`. Any clue how i can resolve this ?

Comment: Ankit you might find that the community would try and answer your questions much more enthusiastically if you also close your questions regularly by accepting answers.

Comment: @Ankit: You have not provided enough information to go on. What does the code look like in your binding statement? Are you doing it in the xml side or the code behind? It is encompassed within a separate function that is forcing HtmlEncoding? Can you post the exact code where this occurs? We like to help, but we like to feel that the help is received and appreciated.

Comment: @Nikhil: The answered queries have already been closed. Rest have not been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bind from server side use something like this

```
btn.Attributes.Add("onclientclick","javascript:functionName(&quot;1&quot;);")
```

Hopefully using `&quot;` instead of `'` should sort your problem out.